# CSS and JavaScript click on a button to create card elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a blank page and a button (somewhere in the top right corner). When I click that button I want to be able to create a square on the page (A contact card). And when I click it again I want to be able to create another card next to it with the same dimensions and so on (i.e every click adds a card till theres  4 in a roll then starts on the bottom of the card untill whole page is filled).

I am unsure on how I can accomplish this. I know how to insert a button and a click event just not sure how I can structure this. Would I need to use flex?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you written any code so far for us to see / help you with...?

Comment: You can have a hidden element, preferably div with desired CSS settings by default on the page. On click of button, you can use 'code'.clone'code' method to clone the existinig div & set it's display to block. This way you will be able to generate n boxes on the UI.

Comment: Hi Stuart, I haven't written any code yet. I am trying to visualize how I can tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to visualize how I can tackle this problem.
>
> Would I need to use `flex`?

In 2016, `flex` would be the best way to approach creating horizontal rows, each containing 4 equal-width elements, yes.

But if you want a legacy-browser solution, you can also use

- `display: inline-block;`
- `float: left;`
- `width --px;`

and a container with an explicitly specified width which means that every `:nth-of-type(4n+1)` element will start on a new row.

For instance:

```
.card {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 100px;
margin: 12px;
}
```

means each card requires `124px` of space (`12px` + `100px` + `12px`).

So if you give the `.card-container` an explicit width of 4 x 124:

```
.card-container {
width: 496px;
}
```

then after every 4 cards, the next card will begin on a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick prototype using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

When pressing the button, the first card with class `card-hidden` is shown and has it's `card-hidden` class removed. The next button press will show the next card until there's no cards left.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
  <button id="button">Add</button>  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card card-hidden col-xs-3">1</div>
      <div class="card card-hidden col-xs-3">2</div>
      <div class="card card-hidden col-xs-3">3</div>
      <div class="card card-hidden col-xs-3">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.card {
  height: 200px;
}
.card-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#button").on("click", function(e) {
 if ($(".card-hidden").length > 0) {
    $(".card-hidden").first().slideToggle(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("card-hidden");
    });
 } else {
   console.log("No more cards to show.");
 }
});
```